# Batch file to list directories recursively in Windows as in linux

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file that lists directories recursively in **Windows** but in a linux-like format.For example consider the following batch file:

```
@echo off
tree /f /a C:\Windows\Boot\dvd>%userprofile%\desktop\tree_output.txt
exit
```

This batch file echoes or saves the output of the tree command in a text file named tree_output.txt in the user's desktop folder ( the /f argument lists all files in subdirectories as well and the /a argument displays the output of tree command in ASCII text format and not in a graphical format).
The tree_output.txt contains the following output:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume System
Volume serial number is 4E00004E 545D:650E
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD
+---EFI
|   |   BCD
|   |   boot.sdi
|   |   
|   \---en-US
|           efisys.bin
|           efisys_noprompt.bin
|           
\---PCAT
     |   BCD
     |   boot.sdi
     |   etfsboot.com
     |   
     \---en-US
           | bootfix.bin
```

However, the **ls -R** command in **linux** would have listed out directories recursively like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\EFI
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\EFI\BCD
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\EFI\boot.sdi
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\EFI\en-US
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\EFI\en-US\efisys_noprompt.bin
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT\BCD
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT\boot.sdi
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT\etfsboot.com
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT\en-US
C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\PCAT\en-US\bootfix.bin
```

**Is there any way to get the above output in a text file in Windows by creating a batch file?** What I have tried to do so far can be summarised as:

- Use the **for** command to check the text file created by the above mentioned batch file to check the presence of the \ character to identify directories (as you can see in the output text file) along with the **findstr** command. This method failed partly because the directories in the root of the directory whose tree is being done ( C:\WINDOWS\BOOT\DVD\ in this case) are identified by the **+** character (as you can see in the output text file).

What I have understood so far is that this cannot be achieved by using any in-built commands with any parameters or arguments from cmd. My idea to solve this is to first get the tree using **tree /f /a** command in a batch file and then sort it out using any other batch file or maybe even a **c++ program** to get the output as in **linux**.

Comment: The equivalent command to `LS` is `DIR`. `dir /s /b`

Comment: And where did you get that misinformation.  Read the help file for the DIR command!

Comment: I am really sorry and ashamed of myself to have not read the man page for the dir command before. That really solved my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
dir /a:d /s /b /o:n
```

The `/s` is used for recursion, `/b` for bare format, so without filesizes etc, `/a:d` is used to only display directories, and `/o:n` is to order by name.

Answer (score 1):

Try Dir /s /b /ad

which is subdirectories bare and directory attribute